# Why are these family instance declarations conflicting?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm getting an error for this code, and I don't understand where the conflict is.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances,
    UndecidableInstances #-}

import Codec.Gray (integralToGray, grayToIntegral)
import Data.List (foldl', unfoldr)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Prelude hiding (read)

class Gene g where
  type Sequence g
  write :: Sequence g -> g -> Sequence g
  read :: Sequence g -> Maybe (g, Sequence g)

instance (Gene a, Sequence a ~ [k], Integral k, Gene k, Sequence k ~ [k]) => Gene [a] where
  type Sequence [a] = Sequence a -- LINE 15
  write xs gs = Nothing -- stub
  read xs = Nothing -- stub


class (Enum g, Bounded g) => Word8Enum g where
  writeEnum :: [Word8] -> g -> [Word8]
  writeEnum xs g = Nothing -- stub

  readEnum :: g -> [Word8] -> Maybe (g, [Word8])
  readEnum _ [] = Nothing
  readEnum model (x:xs) = Nothing -- stub

instance (Word8Enum g) => Gene g where
  type Sequence g = [Word8] -- LINE 29
  write = writeEnum
  read = readEnum undefined
```

When I load my code into GHC, I get the following error:

```
λ> :l amy4
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( amy4.hs, interpreted )

amy4.hs:15:8:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      type Sequence [a] -- Defined at amy4.hs:15:8
      type Sequence g -- Defined at amy4.hs:29:8
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an instance such as

```
instance (Word8Enum g) => Gene g where
   ...
```

GHC considers only the right hand side of the instance arrow when matching instances. I.e., constraints aren't considered. So `Gene g` overlaps with any other instance, and in particular the one for `Gene [a]` above.

Overlapping instances are allowed under certain conditions, but overlapping associated types or type families are not (they will be, in some restricted cases, in upcoming releases of GHC). Therefore, you get the error on the two `Sequence` declarations.

Comment: Ah... so the reason that the Prelude can have both `instance Show a => Show [a]` and `instance Show Bool`, for example, is that `Show` doesn't involve type families. I guess I'll have to redesign this.

Comment: @mhwombat `Bool` is not a variable, so it doesn't overlap with `[a]`.  If you try to define an `instance Show g`, it would overlap.

Answer (score 7):

For information about allowing overlapping type families in future GHCs, see [this ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4259).
It's also worth pointing out that with [closed type families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Closed_family_simplification), some (most? all?) overlap is allowed. For example, the following does not work as an *open* type family:

```
type family NextListElt (xs :: [*]) (a :: *) :: *
type instance NextListElt (a ': b ': xs) a = b
type instance NextListElt (b ': c ': xs) a = NextListElt (c ': xs) a
```

but compiles as a closed type family:

```
type family NextListElt (xs :: [*]) (a :: *) :: * where
  NextListElt (a ': b ': xs) a = b
  NextListElt (b ': c ': xs) a = NextListElt (c ': xs) a
```