# Polymorphic type family instance in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-families

I'm trying to write code to simulate random variables, and I want to keep things as polymorphic as possible. This may involve the use of type families, which are completely new to me.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}


data TrivialDist a = Trivial a

getVal :: TrivialDist a -> a
getVal (Trivial x) = x

class JointDist d a where
    toTrivialDist :: d a -> TrivialDist [a]

data TrivialJointDist a = TrivialJoint [a]

instance JointDist TrivialJointDist a where
    toTrivialDist :: TrivialJointDist a -> TrivialDist [a]
    toTrivialDist (TrivialJoint xs) = Trivial xs

class Simulable s a where
    type Samp s a :: *
    -- generates infinite stream of random samples from a distribution
    samples :: s a -> IO [Samp s a]
    -- generates a single random sample from a distribution
    sample :: s a -> IO (Samp s a)
    sample = fmap head . samples

instance Simulable TrivialDist a where
    type Samp TrivialDist a = a
    samples :: TrivialDist a -> IO [a]
    samples (Trivial x) = return $ repeat x

instance (JointDist d a) => Simulable d a where
    type Samp d a = [a]
    samples :: d a -> IO [[a]]
    samples = samples . toTrivialDist
```

When I load it into ghci, I get this error:

```
test.hs:30:10: error:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      Samp TrivialDist a = a -- Defined at test.hs:30:10
      Samp d a = [a] -- Defined at test.hs:40:10
   |
30 |     type Samp TrivialDist a = a
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, 0 modules loaded.
```

This issue seems to resemble the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593730/why-are-these-family-instance-declarations-conflicting) (the explanation seems to be that GHC can't distinguish the types based on the constraints), but no solution was proposed.

I can get the code to compile if I change the last instance declaration to:

```
instance Simulable TrivialJointDist a where
    type Samp TrivialJointDist a = [a]
    samples :: TrivialJointDist a -> IO [[a]]
    samples = samples . toTrivialDist
```

However, I then lose the advantage of polymorphism, as I would need to make separate instance declarations for each subtype of `JointDist d a`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Correct: you must make separate instance declarations for each instance of `JointDist`. That said there's several code smells here that make me think a much simpler design is warranted. Perhaps it would be possible to give better advice if you can answer this question: is there an instance of `JointDist` which is *not* isomorphic to a `TrivialDist` (and if so, what does it look like)?

Comment: Alternatively you might want to check out some of the libraries that provide random variables for you. My preference is MonadBayes which implements a probability monad that allows sampling, conditioning, and inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After monkeying around a bit, I think I've found a solution that uses equality constraints instead of explicit type families:

```
class Simulable s a b where
    -- generates infinite stream of random samples from a distribution
    samples :: s a -> IO [b]
    -- generates a single random sample from a distribution
    sample :: s a -> IO b
    sample = fmap head . samples

instance (b ~ a) => Simulable TrivialDist a b where
    samples :: TrivialDist a -> IO [a]
    samples (Trivial x) = return $ repeat x

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (JointDist d a, b ~ [a]) => Simulable d a b where
    samples :: d a -> IO [[a]]
    samples = samples . toTrivialDist
```

The `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` pragma instructs GHC to allow the `TrivialDist a b` instance to overlap the `d a b` instance (otherwise we get an error).