# Allow conflicting family instance declarations in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I have 2 type families `ToYao` and `ToValue`. A "value" in this case evaluates to 2 "yao" that are in a tuple. There are 2 instances for ToYao that convert either a character or a list of characters to its yao counterpart `Yao [a] -> [Yao]`. The problem is that when I have a list of values, I would like it to be in the form `Yao [Value] -> ([yao list 1], [yao list 2])`

My question is how do I make a default generic instance for the class, but also have specialised instances?

Im aware that [GHC considers only the right hand side of the instance arrow when matching instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593730/why-are-these-family-instance-declarations-conflicting/17594004#17594004), but I was still hoping that their would be a way to make it so that GHC looks at specific instances first, and if none match then go to the generic.

Here's the code (other instances emitted)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

-- | The yao literal that can only be 0 or 1.
newtype Yao = Yao Char deriving (Show, Eq)

-- | The ToYao typefamily provides a way to convert various types to Yao by uisng the `toYao` function
class ToYao a where
    -- | The typefamily wrapper for Yao
    type YaoType a
    {-| Converts a type to its Yao counterpart, and raises an error if its "a" is not '0' or '1'.
      
    >>> toYao '1'
    Right (Yao '1')
    >>> toYao "101010" 
    Right [Yao '1',Yao '0',Yao '1',Yao '0',Yao '1',Yao '0']
    >>> toYao $ Just '1'
    Right $ Just (Yao '1')
    -}
    toYao :: a -> Either String (YaoType a)

-- | Implement ToYao for the '0' and '1' characters only
instance ToYao Char where
    type YaoType Char = Yao
    toYao c
      | c `elem` ['0', '1'] = Right $ Yao c
      | otherwise = Left "Yao can only be '0' or '1'"

instance ToYao Value where
    type YaoType Value = (Yao, Yao)
    toYao v
      | v == Value '6'  = toYao ('0','1')
      | v == Value '7'  = toYao ('1','1')
      | v == Value '8'  = toYao ('0','0')
      | v == Value '9'  = toYao ('1','0')
      | otherwise       = Left ""         -- this will never occur

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} ToYao [Value] where
  type YaoType [Value] = ([Yao], [Yao])
  toYao xs
    | length xs == 6 = bimap sequence sequence $ unzip <$> traverse toValue xs
    | otherwise = Left "Length of [Yao] and [Value] must be 6"

-- | Implement ToYao for strings and lists of characters
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} ToYao a => ToYao [a] where
    type YaoType [a] = [YaoType a]
    toYao xs
      | length xs == 6 = traverse toYao xs
      | otherwise = Left "Length of a [Yao] must be 6"

-- | The value literal that can only be 6, 7, 8 or 9
newtype Value = Value Char deriving (Show, Eq)

-- | The ToValue typefamily provides a way to convert various types to Values by uisng the `toValue` function
class ToValue a where
    -- | The typefamily wrapper for Yao
    type ValueType a
    {-| Converts a type to its Value counterpart, and raises an error if its "a" is not '6', '7', '8' or '9'.
      
    >>> toValue '7'
    Value '7'
    >>> toValue "787879" 
    [Value '7',Value '8', Value '7', Value '8', Value '7',Value '9']
    >>> toValue $ Just 9
    Just (Value '9')
    -}
    toValue :: a -> Either String (ValueType a)
```

Any help appreciated :D

Comment: shouldn't one be overlapping and the other overlappable?

Comment: Minor correction: `YaoType` is the (associated) type family and `ToYao` is the type class. Same for `ValueType`/`ToValue`.

Comment: Why not change the `ToYao [a]` instance to `ToYao [Char]`? Then you won't have overlapping instances at all.

Comment: The whole typeclass looks dubious to me. The two sanity questions you should always ask before introducing a class are **1.** can you formulate _laws_ for it? **2.** will you actually be able to write useful code that is _polymorphic_ over the class? -- There are _some_ examples where both of these checks fail and the class is nevertheless good, but usually it's an indication that you should simply use multiple concrete definitions instead.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I understand where you are coming from, I'm a beginner in Haskell and though that `toYao` being a function that can convert most things to yao would be better than having multiple `XtoYao` functions. I did what @Noughtmare said and it seems to work. If theirs a better way to do this please let me know :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It says [here](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#instance-overlap) that you can use both. It it better to use overlapping and overlappable instead of overlaps?

Comment: Well, if you're a beginner I would definitely recommend you stay away from overlapping instances! There are some alternatives that could work for what you want, but it's hard to tell what's best without more context.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ok thanks! I finished reading LYAH and the wiki (again) recently, and am making a personal project to learn(cram) as many interesting things in haskell that seem cool to me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell doesn't support conflicting instances for "open" type families, regardless of whether or not the type family is standalone or associated with a type class.  A quick fix is to define a closed type family, separate from your class and instances:

```
type family YaoType a where
  YaoType Char = Yao
  YaoType Value = (Yao, Yao)
  YaoType [Value] = ([Yao], [Yao])
  YaoType [a] = [YaoType a]
```

This means you can't add any new instances without modifying this closed type family, but that's the price you pay for being able to resolve conflicting type family instances.

The reason for this restriction has to do with the fact that overlapping instances with compatible type family instances can be resolved by the type checker without having to resolve the overlap -- even if two or more instances overlap, their method types are all compatible.  If we allow type family instances to be selected as part of the resolution of overlapping instances, we can't type check a polymorphic function involving that type class without checking every possible instance (which violates the whole idea of open type class / type family declarations).

Specifically, if we have "normal" overlapping instances like:

```
class Foo a where
  toFoo :: a -> Int
instance {-# LANGUAGE OVERLAPPING #-} Foo [Char] where
  toFoo _ = 42
instance {-# LANGUAGE OVERLAPPABLE #-} Foo [a] where
  toFoo x = length x
```

then we can type check:

```
twoFoo :: Foo [a] => [a] -> (Int, Int)
twoFoo x = (toFoo x, toFoo (x ++ x))
```

without deciding whether `a` is `Char` or not `Char`.  But if we have overlapping instances with incompatible type family instances:

```
class Foo a where
  type FooType a
  toFoo :: a -> FooType a
instance {-# LANGUAGE OVERLAPPING #-} Foo [Char] where
  type FooType [Char] = String
  toFoo _ = "forty two"
instance {-# LANGUAGE OVERLAPPABLE #-} Foo [a] where
  type FooType [a] = Int
  toFoo x = length x
```

then we can't type check a function like:

```
twoFoo :: Foo [a] => [a] -> FooType [a]
twoFoo x = 2 * toFoo x
```

unless we check it for `a ~ Char` (where type checking fails) and "all other `a`" (where type checking succeeds) separately.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much for the detailed answer! It makes a lot of sense to me; so if I'm understanding correctly (and pls correct me if I'm wrong): With closed type families, we already have all the possibilities of what `FooType` can be/know that `toFoo` will always return a specific type, whereas with open type families, we define `FooType` per instance and thus cannot type check it without knowing all other instances that could define `toFoo` differently. Side note: do you have any recommendations for learning resources to understand types and type families better? Thanks :D